# google ml kit object detection not detecting objects

Tags: flutter, dart, google-mlkit

I have integrated object detection but its not detecting. tflite model is keeps assets folder.
face is getting captured but then objects are not. If any object found it should prompt message to user.

Below is the code where I integrated face detection and object detection.It first captures image and face is detected, next objects on face if any, should be detected.

````
   if (!isCaptureEnabled) return;
   setState(() {
     _text = 'Lassi';
     isCaptureEnabled = false;
   });

   // setState(() {
   //   appStatus = 'Waiting';
   // });

   final faces = await _faceDetector.processImage(inputImage);
   if (faces.isNotEmpty) {
     if (inputImage.metadata?.size != null &&
         inputImage.metadata?.rotation != null) {
       final painter = FaceDetectorPainter(
           faces, inputImage.metadata!.size, inputImage.metadata!.rotation);
       _customPaint = CustomPaint(painter: painter);
       final imglib.Image yuvdecodedImage = decodeYUV420SP(inputImage);

       final isBlurry = isImageBlurry(yuvdecodedImage);

       setState(() {
         croppedImages = [];
       });
       if (_objectDetector == null) return;

       final objects = await _objectDetector!.processImage(inputImage);
       if (inputImage.metadata?.size != null &&
           inputImage.metadata?.rotation != null) {
         final painter = ObjectDetectorPainter(
           objects,
           inputImage.metadata!.size,
           inputImage.metadata!.rotation,
           cameraLensDirection,
         );
         _customPaint = CustomPaint(painter: painter);
         for (final object in objects) {
           if (object.labels.contains('Helmet') ||
               object.labels.contains('Cloth') ||
               object.labels.contains('Glasses')) {
             // Prompt to remove the detected object
             ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
               content: Text('Remove the object that covers your face.'),
               duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
               backgroundColor: Colors.red,
             ));
           }
           if (_isDetecting) return;
           _isDetecting = true;

           for (final face in faces) {
             final left = (face.boundingBox.left < 0
                     ? 0
                     : face.boundingBox.left.toDouble())
                 .toInt();
             final top = (face.boundingBox.top < 0
                     ? 0
                     : face.boundingBox.top.toDouble())
                 .toInt();
             final width = (face.boundingBox.right > yuvdecodedImage.width
                         ? yuvdecodedImage.width
                         : face.boundingBox.right.toDouble())
                     .toInt() -
                 left;
             final height = (face.boundingBox.bottom > yuvdecodedImage.height
                         ? yuvdecodedImage.height
                         : face.boundingBox.bottom.toDouble())
                     .toInt() -
                 top;

             //Crop the image using the calculated values
             final croppedImage = imglib.copyCrop(yuvdecodedImage,
                 x: left, y: top, width: width, height: height);

             //Convert the cropped Image into Base64
             final base64Image = base64Encode(imglib.encodeJpg(croppedImage));
             final base64ImageFull =
                 base64Encode(imglib.encodeJpg(yuvdecodedImage));
             if (face.contours.isNotEmpty &&
                 face.rightEyeOpenProbability != null &&
                 face.leftEyeOpenProbability != null &&
                 face.rightEyeOpenProbability! > 0.5 &&
                 face.leftEyeOpenProbability! > 0.5 &&
                 face.contours.isNotEmpty) {
               //Add to crop image list (base64)
               if (isBlurry == false) {
                 croppedImages.add(base64ImageFull);
                 // croppedImages.insert(0, base64ImageFull);
               } else {
                 ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                   content: Text('Face is blurred'),
                   duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                   backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                 ));
               }
             } else {
               //Show snackbar if the image is blurred
               ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                 content: Text('Face is not clear'),
                 duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                 backgroundColor: Colors.red,
               ));
             }
             //print("croppedImages: ${croppedImages.length}");
           }
           //Navigate to next page
           if (croppedImages.isNotEmpty) {
             await _faceDetector.close();

             //Navigate to next page
             setState(() {
               appStatus = 'Navigating';
             });

             if (widget.isCreateUser == true) {
               Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                   context,
                   MaterialPageRoute(
                       builder: (context) => CreateUserPage(
                             imageFull: croppedImages[0], //yuvdecodedImage,
                           )),
                   (route) => false);
               setState(() {
                 isCaptureEnabled = true;
               });
             } else {
               try {
                 Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                     context,
                     MaterialPageRoute(
                         builder: (context) => NextPage(
                               imageFull: croppedImages[0], // yuvdecodedImage,
                               apiResponse: "",
                             )),
                     (route) => false);
               } catch (error) {
                 setState(() {
                   appStatus = 'Search: Error';
                 });
                 ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                   content: Text('Search: $error'),
                   duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                   backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                 ));
               }
             }
           } else {
             String text = 'Faces found: ${faces.length}\n\n';

             for (final face in faces) {
               // ignore: avoid_print
               print('face: ${face.boundingBox}');
               text += 'face: ${face.boundingBox}\n\n';
             }
             _text = text;
             // set _customPaint to draw boundingRect on top of image
             _customPaint = null;
           }
         }
       }  
       setState(() {
         isCaptureEnabled = true;
       });
     }
   }
 }```
````